# Can custom Sharepoint 2007 workflows handle time-sensitive events?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow-foundation

I need to create a custom workflow for use in Sharepoint 2007. The crux of it is that a workflow task will be created in SP when the workflow is started and if that task isn't complete in X minutes, an email should be sent reminding the user to complete the task.

Is there a mechanic in WF that can handle this? From what I'm reading (totally new to WF) it doesn't appear there is and I really need some external process that checks all task items regularly and notifies accordingly. It doesn't appear I can handle this solely in a WF.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SharePoint designer to create your workflow, then there is no easy solution to this.

But if you're make a "real" workflow using Visual Studio then the solution is something like this:

- Create Task
- Code (Calculate when to send e-mail)
- While (Task not completed/deleted)

  - Listen (With 3 branches)

    1. Task Modified

       - Code (Check if completed)
       - What else you might want
    2. Task Deleted

       - What should happen in this case
    3. Delay

       - Send E-mail
       - Code (Calculate new time to escalate)

Comment: Looks like those delays will work. I just wish I could either unit test this thing or at least debug it.